# Nodes and arrows from tikz not showing when using input, the rest from pgfplots is ok

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In general I create all my tikzpictures in separate tex files which I then input using the `\input` command to a main tex file.

I started using a template from my university for the main file and now I see that any `\draw` or `\node` do not show up (or at least I don't see them within the plotting area) in the final pdf when compiled.

Only the pgfplots seems to work. I have included the packages for **tikz** and **pgfplots** in the main file and still nothing. In one of my plots the nodes did show up but they had another scale in the y axis (I had to multiply by 10 the values of the y coordinates in the nodes to fix them to the right place).

Any idea why the insertion of the tikzpicture using `\input{mytikz.tex}` do not work properly for tikz items? and how to fix it?

Here is an example of what I am talking:

1. Compiling tex file with only the tikzpicture
   [image: a tex file with only tikzpicture]
2. Compiling the main file
   [image: main file with text and input figure]

Example code:

```
    \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots} 


    % Libraries
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    % Others
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

    \begin{document}

    %\resizebox{6cm}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[dots/.style={circle,draw=blue,fill=blue, inner sep=-1pt}]

        \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        scale only axis, % scale axis to specified size, otherwise the complete picture takes the size
    %   scale=1,
    %   normalsize,
    %   x=8cm,
    %   xmin=1, xmax=200,
    %   ymin=-1, ymax=0,
        width=6cm,
        height={},
    %   ticks=none,
        axis x line=top,
        axis y line=left,
        y axis line style={stealth-},
    %   xlabel={$ln(\tau_{rz})$},
        x label style={above,font=\large,at={(1,1)}},
    %   ylabel={$\delta_{head}$},
        y label style={font=\Large},
        legend style={at={(0.01,0.01)},anchor=south west,font=\scriptsize},
        legend columns=1,
        legend style={/tikz/column 3/.style={column sep=10pt}},
        legend cell align=left,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        ]

            \addlegendimage{empty legend}
            \addlegendentry{A $\rightarrow$ B  $\Delta\tau$=0 with t}
            \addlegendimage{empty legend}
            \addlegendentry{A $\rightarrow$ C  $\Delta\tau$=change with t}

            % NC-line
            \addplot[name path global=nc1,domain=30:60]{-0.01*ln(x)}
            coordinate [pos=0.3] (K1)
            coordinate [pos=0.6] (K2)
            ;   
            \addplot[name path global=nc2,domain=60.01:160]{-0.1*ln(x)+(0.1*ln(60)-0.01*ln(60))}
            coordinate [pos=0.3] (L1)
            coordinate [pos=0.4] (L2)
            ;

            % Isotachs
            \addplot[domain=50.01:160]{-0.1*ln(x)+(0.1*ln(60.01)-0.01*ln(60))-0.03};    
            \addplot[name path global=iso2,domain=45.01:160]{-0.1*ln(x)+(0.1*ln(60.01)-0.01*ln(60))-0.05};
            \addplot[domain=40.01:160]{-0.1*ln(x)+(0.1*ln(60.01)-0.01*ln(60))-0.07};

            % Dots  
            \node[dots,label=right:\normalsize A] (A1) at (100,-0.092) {};

            \node[dots,label=right:\normalsize B] (B1) at (100,-0.092-0.05) {};
            \node[dots,label=left:\normalsize C] (C1) at (90,-0.081-0.05) {};

            \node[label=right:\normalsize time] (t11) at (120,-0.092) {};
            \node[] (t22) at (120,-0.092-0.05) {};


            % Arrows
            \draw [->,black,thick,shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt,densely dashed] (A1.south)--(B1.north);
            \draw [->,black,thick,shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt,densely dashed] (A1.south)--(C1.north);
            \draw [|->,red,thick,shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt,solid] (t11.south)--(t22.north);


        \end{semilogxaxis}


        \end{tikzpicture}
    %}          
    \end{document}
```

After commenting out the preamble of the single file, I input it in the main file:

```
\begin{figure}
\input{../plots/model/myplot.tex}
\end{figure}
```

My plot is in semilog scale by the way. After removing the scale, the nodes show somewhere in the plot space, but I don't know why the are not matching the assigned coordinates.

[image: nodes in wrong place]

Comment: Do you have some sort of `every node` or `every picture` type of `tikzset` style settings in some place?

Comment: But your example code doesn't show the problem mentioned.

Comment: percusse, I do not have any type of tikzset and Gonzalo, my example is the pictures I added, the code is more to illustrate what I do, my functions is more complex. I forgot to add some node comand in the example code.

Comment: @Gabriel, is content of your image complete or is a part of it imported from some subfolder? If the latter is the case, than you have problem with defining paths to image and "sub image". Otherwise, if the image is complete  in one file, it should appear complete in main file.

Comment: @Zarko the image is complete in its own tex file. I then comment the preamble since the same things are in the main file, so when I use \input I just pull everything inside the \begin{tikzpicture} to \end{tikzpicture}. The path seems ok. I just added a picture without the semilogx scale to show that the nodes are floating somewhere in the plot space.

Comment: I cleaned and added the original code so you can take a look. Again, when compiled in the main file, the nodes goes crazy.

Comment: The description you have points to the suspicion that you have `overlay, remember picture` setting somewhere. Can you search for things before this TikZ file? Or just leave this TikZ picture in the copy of your master TeX file.

Comment: I did as you said, just left the figure and took everything from the master file. Still doesn't work. This is the master file https://github.com/Micket/chalmers can it be wrong?

Comment: Apparently it is a bug in the master file (template), I tried with a fresh template and a simple pfgplot with tikz nodes and same problem. Any clue? The one I use the is the Doctoral one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of the template Gabriel uses, and I do make use of overlay and remember picture for the cover page.

But I'm pretty sure that the real solution to this problem is to make use of `axis cs` when specying the nodal points in the plot axis c.s.

The [pgfplots gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) show multiple uses of this.

```
\node[...] at (axis cs:0.18,0.74,0.08) {...};
```

(I could be wrong)

Comment: I think your `remember picture` setting might have leaked out if you had used `every picture/.style` otherwise this shouldn't be a problem. And since version 1.11 assumes `axis cs` for the naked coordinates if it is not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: This solved the problem, I will keep checking all my other plots. Thanks to all!

Comment: @percusse I only used `remember picture, overlay` on a single tikzpicture in the front matter. No tikzset or anything my template. My template doens't include pgfplots package at all, so I don't try to set any compat version either, so likely, in this case version 1.11 wasn't in use.